# Fourier transformations in Simon's quantum paper

Tags: functions, algorithms, boolean-algebra, quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation

I am reading [this paper](http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse599/01wi/papers/simon_qc.pdf) by Simon. This is one of the earliest quantum algorithm papers. In the paper he presents a routine starting at the end of page six. The first step runs a Fourier transformation on a string of $n$ zeroes producing $2^{-\frac{n}{2}} \sum_x |x\rangle$. I understand that $x \in \{0, 1\}^n$.

Does the summation mean sum over all possible permutation of $\{0, 1\}^n$? If so, still I don't see how this sum is equal to $|0^n\rangle$.

At the same time, I don't see where the $y$ comes from in step 3.

Comment: I can't give a full answer, but the sum is over all *elements* of $\{0,1\}^n$. The result of step 1 isn't supposed to be equal to $\mid 0^n\rangle$: instead of $n$ independent copies of $\mid 0\rangle$, you get $n$ independent copies of $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(\mid 0\rangle+\mid 1\rangle)$.

Comment: @ColinMcQuillan, I see. In what sense then it is a Fourier transformation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Fourier transform $F$ is defined (here) as
$$
F|x\rangle = 2^{-n/2}\sum_{y\in \{0,1\}^n} (-1)^{x\cdot y}|y\rangle.
$$
So the answer to you last question is that $y$ is a dummy variable indexing the sum.  Not that if we apply $F$ to the state $|0^n\rangle$, we get
$$
F|0^n\rangle= 2^{-n/2}\sum_{x\in \{0,1\}^n} (-1)^{0^n\cdot x}|x\rangle = 2^{-n/2}\sum_{x\in \{0,1\}^n}|x\rangle.
$$
This is step 1. I haven't gone through the details but I think step 2 is to introduce $n$ more qubits (WLOG in the state $0^n\rangle$) and perform a sequence of gates $U_f$ which maps 
$$
U_f |x\rangle \otimes |0^n\rangle = |x\rangle\otimes|f(x)\rangle =:|x,f(x)\rangle.
$$
Now step 3 is just to apply $F$ again on the first $n$ qubits:
\begin{align}
F\otimes \mathbb I \left(2^{-n/2}\sum_{x\in \{0,1\}^n}|x,f(x)\rangle\right) &= 2^{-n/2}\sum_{x\in \{0,1\}^n}F|x\rangle\otimes|f(x)\rangle,\\ &= 2^{-n} \sum_{y\in \{0,1\}^n}\sum_{x\in \{0,1\}^n}(-1)^{x\cdot y}|y\rangle\otimes|f(x)\rangle.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks! Is $y \in \{ 0, 1 \}^n$ always true?